# Newlines in a macro with #

Tags: c++, macros

Why are newlines, spaces and tabs ignored by # in a macro and replaced by exactly one space?

Is there a way to get theses white spaces into the string generated by #?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define TOSTR(s) #s

int main() {
    cout <<
TOSTR(a newline at the end please
three   spaces
        tab first
) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a newline at the end please three spaces tab first
```

(There are no newlines, no three spaces and no tab)

Comment: Why?  Because the language standard allows/mandates it.

Comment: Why := What is the reasoning behind it? Are there issues if it would behave otherwise? Am I the first person on earth trying to do this? How do other people work around it?

Comment: I don't know why, I guess the standard authors made a call many years ago, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to write the newline `\n` or tab `\t` character

Comment: And what about the spaces?

Comment: @Danvil: Is this really a problem in practice?  What kind of replacement are you trying to do where the lack of exact whitespace is a problem, and you can't solve by using a string literal rather than a macro?

Comment: I want to add source code for another language into my C++ source file which is given as a string to a compiler. If there is an error in this inline source code, the other language compiler tells me at what line. But my TOSTR macro generates a string which is one huge line so theses error messages are useless. And with Python it would not even work...

Comment: Now I could use a string literal, but adding white spaces manually is tedious as the source code is actually not that short...